# Glade: How change program interface language?

Tags: language, user-interface, gtk, build

I'm using Glade (GTK+ 2 User Interface Builder). But I'm from Brazil, and my Ubuntu 10.10 is in portuguese.

How can I make Glade use English by default language?

P.S: I don't want to turn all my system in english, its just for Glade program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either override the language setting then starting glade like `LANG=C glade-3` or simply delete the translation file /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/glade3.mo.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I don't know how you dropped here (one question from 5 months ago), but thank you so much!

Comment: Great solution for annoying problem! I'd just add the Windows version: `cmd /c "set LANG=C && glade-3.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

@Fabel 's solution didn't work for me. (I'm on ubuntu 16.04 with glade 3.18.3)

I had to set the variable `LC_ALL=C` instead of `LANG=C`. Like this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C glade &
```

You could also create an alias to that with

```
# ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile
alias glade="LC_ALL=C glade"
```

or even creating your own `glade-in-english.desktop` file at `~/.local/share/applications/glade-in-english.desktop`.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I want to improve answer from Zvika to run Glade from Windows 10.
I create a batch file (glade.bat) in Windows desktop, and then type in the glade.bat:

`c:`

`cd\msys64\mingw64\bin`

`cmd /c "set LANG=C && glade.exe"`

Now you can run glade.bat from Desktop and Glade will be opened with English language